# Get a Variable from One Driver’s Script and Use It's Value in Another Driver’s Script

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I have an issue where I need to be able to access a variable from one script inside of another script.  Here is a short version of the code I’m working with:

```
import bpy

def RotateMonthDisc_v2(earthOrbitRotation):

   totalDaysLost = ((earthOrbitRotation/6.28)*daysLostEachYear)-totalDaysGained 
   totalDaysLost_Radians = (totalDaysLost*lengthOfOneDay_Radians)*-1


   return totalDaysLost_Radians

bpy.app.driver_namespace['RotateMonthDisc_v2'] = RotateMonthDisc_v2
```

I would like to be able to get the value of the totalDaysLost variable (not to be confused with totalDaysLost_Radians)  inside of another driver’s script, but I wasn't sure how to go about doing that, or if it’s even possible to do it.

If it’s not possible, I was wondering if it might be possible to use the same script on two objects, but have it behave differently on each one.  Maybe with an if statement saying, if it’s this object, return this variable, but if it’s this other object, return this other variable.

Thanks a bunch to anyone willing to help!